# When should Laravel events be fired and queued versus running a synchronous function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just want to know when Laravel events be fired and queued against running a synchronous function..Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: "it depends".

Executing logic synchronously adds some execution time to processing user request, while keeping the logic and architecture a bit simpler. It also lets you get the result of event execution in the request and return it to the user.

Executing tasks in the background makes request processing lighter but requires to to set up a scheduler that would process queued events. It also makes it impossible to deliver the result to the user in the response.

So a few rules you could follow:

- if you need to show the result of the event processing to the user immediately - process events synchronously
- if you do not need to pass the result to the user - see how much overhead it adds to processing time and decide if it's still acceptable to do that synchronously - if yes, go for it. If not, queue the events
- if you need to process the events one by one because of some deadlocks that might occur on the database or for any other reason, use queues for that

There are many factors to consider and it all depends on the requirements of your application.